# how to create python threads to send parallel HTTP requests at once

Tags: python, http

I'm trying to send multiple HTTP requests at the same time using python, receiving the responses are not essential.
I'm trying to create multiple threads to send multiple http requests at once. If someone can show an simple example I'm very grateful.

Comment: [Grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) and [requests-with-futures](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures) do this for you. Note that parallelism in Python is impossible thanks to the [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock), so the best you can hope for is concurrent requests, for which coroutines are better suited than threads.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact you havnt tried to do any coding, what's wrong with:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.fooboo.com"
for each in range(100000)
  requests.get(url)
```

Or better put, what do you mean by "same time"?

Comment: Thank you, by ''same time'' I meant sending multiple requests at a exact time point. lets say if I want to send 10 request at 10.00:00:00 pm. I thought of creating threads, so I can run/start all those threads at a  exact time.

Comment: in a loop it sends requests one by one, I want to send all of them at once.